# Correct typos in date with python3

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

If someone inserts a string '2021-11-31' that doesn't exist as a date.
How to correct the date like '2021-11-30'(last day of month) or '2021-12-01'(first day) with python?

The input date can be '2021-02-34' or '2021-12-35' or many wrong input.. and I want to make it a last day of month or a first day of next month.

The point is

1. The program should know that the date is wrong or correct
2. and then correct the date

Thank you!

Comment: "The program should know that the date is wrong or correct" Seems impossible. If you see "2022-11-09" it looks correct, but what if what I mean is 11th of September?

Comment: "and then correct the date" seems impossible. Even if you could determine that the date is incorrect, you cannot know what date was meant.

Comment: @Yunnosch Ahh I was trying to correct date only if the date is an impossible date. like my example '2021-02-35'.. it's out of the correct range of a month. I wanted to change it to a nearest date so it can be with in correct day range in a month. Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] and make that clear within the question.

Comment: An incorrect date like 2021-11-31, should it be shifted forward (2021-12-01) or rolled back to the end of the month (2021-11-30)?

Comment: @MrFuppes Yes.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [Yunnosch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7733418/yunnosch) in previous comments, you can't be sure the date is "correct".

I guess you're assuming the date format to be `YYYY-MM-DD` and want to constrain `DD` to be within 1-31 (or 1-28, 1-29, 1-30 depending on the month).

Here is a simple function that does this :

```py
import calendar


def rectify_day(dt: str) -> str:
    """
    Rectify the date and month of a date.
    If the day part is greater than the last day of this month,
    it will constrain the day to be the last day of month.
    """
    year_s, month_s, day_s = dt.split("-")   # split the elements of the date
    year = int(year_s)                       # convert them to integers
    month = int(month_s)
    day = int(day_s)
    last_day_of_month = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1] # get the last day of this month
    day = min(day, last_day_of_month)        # constrain the day to max possible value

    return f"{year}-{month:>02d}-{day:>02d}" # returns a formatted string
```

Use it like that :

```py
>>> rectify_day("2021-01-32")
'2021-01-31'
>>> rectify_day("2021-02-29")
'2021-02-28'
>>> rectify_day("2021-01-10")
'2021-01-10'
>>> rectify_day("2021-12-12")
'2021-12-12'
```